# Find and Replace in Laravel Collection

Tags: laravel, collections, laravel-5.8

I am trying to update a laravel collection with another collection.  Here are my collections :

```
$acc = DB::table('accounts')
    ->where('accounts.branchid', $branch_id)
    ->select('code','title','opbal','clbal')->get();
$rslt = DB::table('journal')
    ->where('journal.branchid', $branch_id)
    ->where(function($q) {$q->where('journal.cancel','!=',1)->orWhereNull('journal.cancel');})
    ->select('code',DB::raw('sum(IFNULL(dr,0) - IFNULL(cr,0)) as total'))->groupBy('code')->Get('code','total');
```

What I want is to update $acc->clbal with $rslt->total where $acc->code = $rslt->code

I tried this but it does not work

```
foreach ($rslt as $row) {
    $getacc = $acc->where('code',$row->code);
    $getacc->clbal = $row->total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
$acc = DB::table('accounts')
    ->where('accounts.branchid', $branch_id)
    ->select('code','title','opbal','clbal')->get();
$rslt = DB::table('journal')
    ->where('journal.branchid', $branch_id)
    ->where(function($q) {$q->where('journal.cancel','!=',1)->orWhereNull('journal.cancel');})
    ->select('code',DB::raw('sum(IFNULL(dr,0) - IFNULL(cr,0)) as total'))->groupBy('code')->Get('code','total');

foreach ($rslt as $row) {
    $getacc = $acc->where('code',$row->code)->first();
    $getacc->update(['clbal' => $row->total]);
}
```